# use of unknown / unmanaged dll in .net application - Get the source code of unknown dll

Tags: c#, vb6, dllimport

I have a dll(PROFKT10.DLL) which is very old and using by vb6 project. i dont even know in which language it is compiled. i need to use this dll in my .Net application but i can not add this as reference and getting the popup message as "Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component".

I tried to import this by using DllImport attribute but here getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred.
Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"

Please anyone help me in getting the source code of this dll solution for the exception or any other suggestions. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you help us by saying what the DLL does and where it came from, in-house or third party?  Do you have the VB6 Declare statement that uses it, or if its a COM DLL an example of a CreateObject call?  As devio says PE Viewer may help.

Comment: Your real problem is your attempt to use code whose provenance is unknown. Time to face up to this.

Comment: Change your "target Machine" to X86 for .net application & then try. This is old question but might be useful for new users.

Answer (score 1):

`BadImageFormatException` can have many causes, see its [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If the DLL dates back to VB6, it might even be a 16bit DLL. In this case, you're out of luck, because 16bit executables are not supported on 64bit Windows.

To find out, google for "DLL PE Viewer" or use [this list](https://blog.malwarebytes.org/threat-analysis/2014/05/five-pe-analysis-tools-worth-looking-at/) for tools that provide information about your DLL.

Comment: VB6 was 32-bit.  It'd have to go back to VB3 or maybe VB4 to be 16-bit

Comment: VB4 was the last version that could build16 bit binaries